# Filter object with an array input

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array in JavaScript like

```
var input =['p1',  'p3'];
```

And my data is like below

```
var data = {p1: { name: 'test1', value:'value1'}, p2: { name : 'test2', value:'value2'}, p3: { name: 'test3', value: 'value3'}}
```

I need to filter  the data object based on the input array. Is there a simple ES6 method to pull it out.

Tia

Answer (score 4):

You can simply start from your input array and map to your data:

```js
var input =['p1', 'p3'];
var data = {p1: { name: 'test1', value:'value1'}, p2: { name : 'test2', value:'value2'}, p3: { name: 'test3', value: 'value3'}}

const result = input.map(x => data[x])

console.log(result)
```

As long as you **do not need** to traverse the data tree.

If you need **recursively to traverse** the object tree you could try something like this:

```js
var input = ['p1', 'p3', 'p4', 'pp'];
var data = {
  p: {
    p1: 'A'
  },
  pa: {
    pb: {
      p3: 'B'
    }
  },
  p4: 'C'
}

// recursivly flatten object keys
const flatten = (obj, a=[]) => Object.entries(obj)
  .reduce((r,[k,v]) => (typeof v == 'object' ? flatten(v,a) : r.push(k), r), a)

// search flattened objects
const searchKeys = (d, t) => 
  d.filter(x => flatten(x).some(x => x.toLowerCase().includes(t.toLowerCase())))

// Break to array of objects
const arr = Object.entries(data).reduce((r,[k,v]) => (r.push({[k]:v}), r), [])

console.log(input.map(x => searchKeys(arr, x)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a snippet that might help you:

```js
const data = {
  p1: {
    name: 'test1',
    value: 'value1'
  },
  p2: {
    name: 'test2',
    value: 'value2'
  },
  p3: {
    name: 'test3',
    value: 'value3'
  }
}
const input = ['p1', 'p2']

console.log(input.map(key => data[key]))
```

this is a simple way to do as per your expectation:

```js
var data = {p1: { name: 'test1', value:'value1'}, p2: { name : 'test2', value:'value2'}, p3: { name: 'test3', value: 'value3'}}
var input=['p1','p2']

console.log(Object.keys(data).map(obj => {
  return input.includes(obj) && data[obj] 
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
let input =['p1',  'p3'];
let data = {p1: { name: 'test1', value:'value1'}, p2: { name : 'test2', value:'value2'}, p3: { name: 'test3', value: 'value3'}}

let res = input.map(x =>  ({[x]:data[x]})) 
console.log(res)
```

output

```
(2) […]
   0: Object { p1: {…} }​
   1: Object { p3: {…} }
```

Answer (score 1):

If by filter *object*, you mean you want an *object* with keys that are in the input array, you can [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) your input array to that object:

```js
var input = ['p1', 'p3'];
var data = {p1: { name: 'test1', value:'value1'}, p2: { name : 'test2', value:'value2'}, p3: { name: 'test3', value: 'value3'}}

var res = input.reduce((a, c) => {
  a[c] = data[c];
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to filter that using `forEach`

```
var input =['p1',  'p3'];
var data = {
      p1: { name: 'test1', value:'value1'},
      p2: { name : 'test2', value:'value2'}, 
      p3: { name: 'test3', value: 'value3'}
}

input.forEach(filter => {
    // Check if this key exists in data
    if (data[filter]) {
         console.log(data[filter])
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Filtering the object based on keys present in the array

```js
var input =['p1',  'p3'];

var data = {p1: { name: 'test1', value:'value1'}, p2: { name : 'test2', value:'value2'}, p3: { name: 'test3', value: 'value3'}}


   var filtered= Object.keys(data)
          .filter( key => input.includes(key))
          .reduce( (res, key) => Object.assign(res, { [key]: data[key] }), {} );
console.log(filtered);
```